# Access insert into statement

Tags: ms-access, insert

So currently im trying to run a Insert into statement in access. So the idea is, you select a movie containing a movie ID and this will open a new form. Then you can choose to watch the movie. Now if you choose to watch the movie, I want to update another table with the current Movie ID, the current Date and some other data. The statement goes a bit like this:

```
INSERT INTO watchhistory (movieID, customer_mail_adress, watch_date, price)
    VALUES ("txtMovieID", "email", NOW(), 2)
```

txtMovieID is the textbox which contains the current movie ID.
Now i've tried several things, but they all don't seem to work. I'm also rather new to access so writing out the code is a bit difficult so far.

Thanks!

Comment: Access is not MySQL unless you have some link and use Access only as a management tool for MySQL. Please use the appropriate tags to make this clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Access the values need to be concatenated, so try something like.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO watchhistory (movieID, customer_mail_adress, watch_date, price) " & _
                    "VALUES (" & Me.txtMovieID & ", '" & Me.txtEmail & "', " & Format(Date(), "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & ", 2)"
```

I have taken the liberty in considering the following,

- **txtMovieID** as **Numeric** type.
- **email** is also a control in the Form, and it is Text type (so enclosed it within the single quotes).
- You would want only the **Date** to be entered, so replaced *Now()* with *Date()*. Also enclosed them within **Format** function to make Access aware the Data Type is Date/Time.

Comment: And might I add you can do the above solution directly in an append query without VBA. Just change 'Me.' to Forms!yourformname!txtMovieID, ...Forms!yourformname!txtEmail and remove the single quotes (since form controls compensate). By the way, Format is not necessary as long as the table column (watch_date) is a date/time type nor is # needed for Date().

Comment: @Parfait, I am sure the solution could be even easier by using a **Bound** form, but the OP wanted to know how to use it in an INSERT statement. Regarding your `nor is # needed for Date()`, I believe you are talking about Append Query, for VBA it is required.

Comment: Forgive me PaulFrancis, in MS Access INSERT statements can be made as a Stored Query or a VBA Query. If OP wanted a stored query the solution would be: INSERT INTO watchhistory (movieID, customer_mail_adress, watch_date, price) VALUES (Forms!yourformname!txtMovieID, Forms!yourformname!email, Date(), 2).